# Freezing a TensorFlow graph with a custom op

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, export, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build a graph with std. TF ops and a custom op. Executing it solely python runs fine but additionally I want to export this graph and reload it again, but TF has difficulties interpreting my custom op when loading.

Here is how I export the graph

**export.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_io
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    #build graph
    my_op = tf.load_op_library('/path/to/.so/')
    my_op = my_op.call_op
    math_op = tf.multiply(my_op(2),4)
    sess.run(math_op)

    #export graph
    oup_names = [None]
    oup_names[0] = sess.graph.get_operations()[-1].name
    constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess,sess.graph.as_graph_def(),oup_names)
    graph_io.write_graph(constant_graph, "./","model.pb", as_text=False)
```

then I'm trying to load `model.pb` via

**import.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.gfile.GFile("./model.pb", "rb") as f:
   graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
   graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
   tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="") #crashes here

#...
```

The error message at this point:

> in import_graph_def raise ValueError('No op named %s in defined
>   operations.' % node.op) ValueError: No op named Example in defined
>   operations.

(btw. `ExampleOp` is the name of my class for my custom op)

If i print the text version of the export I receive for my custom op:

```
node {
  name: "Example/inp"
  op: "Const"
  device: "/device:GPU:0"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_INT32
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "value"
    value {
      tensor {
        dtype: DT_INT32
        tensor_shape {
        }
        int_val: 2
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "Example"
  op: "Example"
  input: "Example/inp"
  device: "/device:GPU:0"
}
```

**My guess:** `TF` is overstrained with `op: "Example"` because it lacks a definition on how to work with this operation (?)

Any ideas on that?

[**Update**]

I guess my bazel-BUILD file for the custom op is incomplete, is there an example how write one in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by adding

```
my_op = tf.load_op_library('/path/to/.so/')
```

also in **import.py** before loading the graph

Comment: Hey, I'm facing the same problem.
Did you do something with my_op other than that line?

Comment: It worked just as described in the answer. However I was using r1.4, maybe this solution is already deprecated

Comment: guess so, I'm using tf v1.11 same version as the person who created the model but I guess our operators are still too experimental..